# how to perfom smooth scrolling to a position without actually having to see the scrolling taking place in a listview?

Tags: android

I have made an Android application in which i have a `ListView` and when the list view loads i wish to show the some middle portion of its adapter, hence i am using the `smoothScrollTo` method in the `ListView`.

The problem with the above method is that i can see the scrolling take place, which i don't want.

I have tried putting a progressDialog when the scrolling is taking place , but i guess due to load on the UI thread, it never shows up. Hence hiding the scrolling taking place behind a progressdialog is out of the question.

I cannot even put the smoothscrolling code in another thread because only the UI thread can touch the UI elements.

How do i avoid the user from actually seeing the scrolling take place?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ScrollTo(x,y) method of ListView instead of smoothScroll

Answer (score 1):

This should make it work,

```
        listView.setSelection(pos);
        View v = listView.getChildAt(pos);
        if (v != null) 
        {
            v.requestFocus();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work you can try this...

```
grd.requestFocusFromTouch(); 
grd.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-5); 
grd.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount());
```

if don't work well you can delete first and second line